# ASP.NET MVC Multiple data inside actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a link like this using an action link:

`<%= Html.ActionLink(item.forename item.surname, "Details", "Members", new { member = item.memberNo }, new {})%>` so I want to create a link using a persons forename and surname as the link. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always perform the following ugliness:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    string.Format("{0} {1}", item.forename, item.surname), 
    "Details", 
    "Members", 
    new { member = item.memberNo }
)%>
```

But the correct way to do this is to use a view model. By the way the correct way to do EVERYTHING in MVC is to use a view model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string MemberNo { get; set; }
}
```

Include properties that are needed by the view in this view model and then you map your model to this view model in the controller so that you simply:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    item.FullName, 
    "Details", 
    "Members", 
    new { member = item.memberNo }
)%>
```

Comment: Hey what about doing it inside JUST the actonlink?

Comment: @Cameron, BAD. Don't do this. Use view models.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the helper why not just write the a tag directly? Sometimes it is easier just to write the tag directly than going through the helpers...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Member", new { member = item.memberNo })">
  @item.foreName @item.surname
</a>
```